# Creating Nsight Tegra Android project and Visual Studio exception

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, tegra

I'm trying to use NVidia CodeWorks with Visual Studio. I'm totally new in Nvidia Tegra world.

I have installed latest Visual Studio 2015 Professional (trial) and CodeWorksforAndroid-1R3-windows.

When I'm trying to create new project (Android Application / Nsight Tegra) - I'm getting this error:

[image]

It reminds mi some Visual Studio addon errors I had before, but I have no idea what to do.

Guys, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the fact that Visual C++ component is not installed on your machine - please, run the VS IDE installer, switch to the Custom setup and install the Visual C++.

Nsight Tegra VS Edition does require the Visual C++ VS IDE component to be installed on the developer's machine.

See the [msdev](http://msdev.developer-works.com/article/29437711/Upgrading+from+Visual+Studio+2015+RC+to+Visual+Studio+2015+failed) for the details.